# Close the userform automatically after validation is completed

Tags: excel, vba, forms, userform

I have created a login screen to authenticate into the excel workbook if a valid password is entered.

code is as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 name_selected = ComboBox1.Text
 pwd_entered = TextBox2.Text
 validation_sheet = "Z"
 act_p_col_num = 3
 Application.Visible = True

 For validation_check = 2 To Worksheets(validation_sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If (Worksheets(validation_sheet).Cells(validation_check, 1) = name_selected) Then
        bk_pd = Worksheets(validation_sheet).Cells(validation_check, act_p_col_num).Value
        If (bk_pd = pwd_entered) Then
            Worksheets("INDIVIDUAL_TRACKER").Select
            MsgBox ("Authentication successful")
            UserForm1.Hide
            'Set UserForm1.Visible = False

        Else
            Application.Visible = False
            MsgBox ("Please enter a valid password! Account will be locked after 3 tries")
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
 Next validation_check
End Sub
```

However this code has been tried using the `unload me` command and `userform1.hide` too which is still throwing me a **run time error 424,object required.**

My objective is to go to the workbook once the authentication passes and the `userform` should be closed automatically.

Can someone help me in resolving this ?

Comment: line `UserForm1.Hide` rises the error?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Any help to fix it ?

Comment: did you already `public dim` your variables in another sub? f.e. `validation_sheet` ?

Comment: Is this code in the Worksheet?  In the UserForm?  In a Code Module?  Have you turned on "Require Variable Definition" / `Option Explicit` in case you have a typo in an object name?

Comment: Is `Userform1` really the name of the userform? `Unload Me` should work i f this code is in the form...

Comment: @Chronocidal The code is under a button click and the name of the object is correct too without a typo.

Comment: @user2075017 And, is the button on a Worksheet, or in the UserForm?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes the code is within the button click and button is in the form...Unload Me has been used and that still throws the error and I am Stuck

Comment: @Chronocidal Button is in the UserForm

Comment: I kinda replicated your code, with a loop, a msgbox, selecting worksheet, and unload me. Worked perfect. What happens if you execute your code step by step? Type `Stop` right at start of your code, execute it as normally you would do, and then go line by line using F8

Comment: I find this whole macro a bit sketchy, you could also just try to `Find` the combobox value and see the password is correct through `Offset`. Also why would you want to continue your macro to run after you found a match? Also what EXACT line does error out?

Comment: @can you upload the file to somewhere with fake data? Maybe checking how you have set it up can throw some light

Comment: `Application.Visible = True` What happens if you delete this line at start of your code? Also, delete `Application.Visible = False` and execute it

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I had added the below lines in addition to my code at the time of workbook open as the objective is to see the login form upon opening the workbook `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`
 `Application.Visible = False`
 `UserForm1.Show`
`End Sub`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Deleting the `application.visible=True` may not solve our purpose as we need to activate the worbook upon successful authentication.How ever your idea made a trigger to jumbling or reshuffling the lines and that did solve the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the next iteration of the for loop is what is actually causing the problem. You try to access the TextBox on the if statement when the form has been unloaded.

Try including the line

```
Exit For
```

After `Unload Me`

Comment: I have tried the below as per your suggestion and no luck yet.  `If (bk_pd = pwd_entered) Then
            Worksheets("INDIVIDUAL_TRACKER").Select
            MsgBox ("Authentication successful")
            Unload Me
            Exit For
            'UserForm1.Hide
            'Set UserForm1.Visible = False
            
        Else

Comment: That should not be the problem, because OP said that line `UserForm1.Hide` is the one raising the error. Your idea is good and I upvoted, but in that case the line that could cause the error would be `TextBox2.Text = ""`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns basically if I had given a valid entires of user name and password,the error is being thrown.However `textbox2.text=""` will be initiated only at the time of wrong password entry.

Answer (score 1):

Reshuffling the `application.visible=True` lines has solved the purpose. Using it in the right place has made it work well.And a use of `Exit For` has been an added advantage.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 name_selected = ComboBox1.Text
 pwd_entered = TextBox2.Text
 validation_sheet = "Z"
 act_p_col_num = 3
 Application.Visible = True

 For validation_check = 2 To Worksheets(validation_sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If (Worksheets(validation_sheet).Cells(validation_check, 1) = name_selected) Then
        bk_pd = Worksheets(validation_sheet).Cells(validation_check, act_p_col_num).Value
        If (bk_pd = pwd_entered) Then
            Unload Me

            'UserForm1.Hide
            'Set UserForm1.Visible = False
            Application.Visible = True
            Worksheets("INDIVIDUAL_TRACKER").Select
            MsgBox ("Authentication successful")
            Exit For
        Else
            'Application.Visible = False
            MsgBox ("Please enter a valid password! Account will be locked after 3 tries")
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
 Next validation_check
End Sub
```

***Thanks to everyone*** who has shed some light on this issue.It was a good brainstorming.Thanks everyone.The issue stands resolved now.